# SAP Crystal reports for VS 2010. Change the query at run time

Tags: crystal-reports, report, feed

I am using SAP CR for VS 2010 in C sharp. i have five tables and i am linking them with the following query:

query = "SELECT Items.AccessionNo, Items.Name, Items.LocalName, Items.Usage, Items.Province, Items.District, Items.VillTown, Items.EthnicCommunity, Arts.Name, Items.PurchasedDonated, Items.PurchasedFrom, Items.YearOfCollection, Items.Material, Items.Height, Items.Width, Items.Length, Items.Circumference, Items.Diameter, Items.Color, Items.Age, Items.Weight, Items.PurchasedValue, Items.Rare, Items.LivingDyingTrad, Items.ManufacturingProcess, Items.PlaceOfManufacturing, Items.ConditionReport, Items.Recommandations, Items.DateOfAddition, Items.Placement, Donators.Name, Collectors.Name, Placement.Name FROM Items INNER JOIN Arts ON Items.ArtId=Arts.ArtId INNER JOIN Donators ON Items.DonatorId=Donators.id INNER JOIN Collectors ON Items.CollectorId=Collectors.id INNER JOIN Placement ON Items.PlacementId=Placement.id WHERE Items.id=" + itemid;

The problem is that the report still shows up multiple results using the already embedded query at the time of design.

I am using the following code to pass the above query

```
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dbconn.conn);
            if (dbconn.conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                dbconn.conn.Open();
            }

            SqlDataAdapter Datadpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataSet dtset = new DataSet("items");
            Datadpt.Fill(dtset);
            //rep is the Report document object already defined
            rep.Load(@"..\..\Reports\CRItem.rpt");
            rep.SetDataSource(dtset);
            CRViewer.ReportSource = rep;
            if (dbconn.conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                dbconn.conn.Close();
            }
            this.CRViewer.RefreshReport();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do the results all have the same `Items.id` value?

Comment: No. Report displays all the rows in database. It is not filtering the data according to query.

Comment: does `this.CRViewer.Refresh();` do anything differently to `this.CRViewer.RefreshReport();`?

Comment: this.CRViewer.Refresh(); is not doing anything different to this.CRViewer.RefreshReport();

Comment: I am stuck on the above issue from couple of days.I finally decided to filter the report contents using parameter field. I appreciate the help from Stackoverflow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

whoooosss.....i got it. the the crystalreportviewer selection formula is separate from report document record selection formula. Record Selection Formula that you've created in crystal report is stored in `ReportDoc.RecordSelectionFormula` property. When you load your ReportDoc to ReportViewer it doesn't adopt the value of `.RecordSelectionFormula` to its `ReportViewer.SelectionFormula` property. so what i did is....

My objects are:

```
ReportDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
ReportViewer As CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer
FlexReportDoc.SetParameterValue("Reference", gsReference)
```

After passing necessary parameters if you have any...

```
ReportViewer.ReportSource = FlexReportDoc
ReportViewer.SelectionFormula = FlexReportDoc.RecordSelectionFormula
```

you need to assign the value of `FlexReportDoc.RecordSelectionFormula` property to `ReportViewer.SelectionFormula`.